# Hidden robots.txt file blocking root domain on www version of site, possible htaccess fix

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I'm trying to find a way to redirect or edit a ghost robots.txt file that is blocking the root domain on the www version of a site.

The robots file in the root domain is not the same as the one which displays when pointing the browser to the URL `https://www.example.com/robots.txt`. However, the robots file being read at that URL does not exist.

It contains the following code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Crawl-delay: 5
```

The file found at `https://example.com/robots.txt` contains this code:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

This file can be edited but as the final URL resolves to the www version of the site it is not the one that is being read by crawlers.

The .htaccess file contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to either identify the hidden robots.txt file and edit its contents or change the htaccess file to use the editable file in place of the blocking file on the www domain?

Comment: Did you check your server's main and/or virtualhost config files?

Comment: I think it was to do with the server file. I checked with the host and they were able to make changes which I was unable to do remotely. The file now reads correctly but had me baffled at the time!